# Alternative means to deleting a git branch (if git branch -d doesn't work)

Tags: windows-7, git

I use git for software development.  I do not use Microsoft OneNote.  However, in some contexts OneNote comes up as an option for the right-click menu on things.  I accidentally pressed it while trying to do something else with a file that was included in my git repo.  I closed out of it, but upon inspecting my git repository, I found it had created a OneNote file in every single directory of my repo.

Furthermore, there is now a git branch labeled `OneNote Table Of Contents.onetoc2`  Note that there are spaces in the branch name.  I was able to delete all of the OneNote files, but I can't get rid of the extra branch.

Is there an alternative means of deleting a branch besides the git branch -d option? I use Windows 7 Home Premium.

Answer (score 1):

Locally-created branches in Git are simply files inside the `.git/refs` directory that contain SHA1 hashes of Git commit objects. Therefore, you can remove these branches by deleting the appropriate files.

This particular branch is probably in the `.git/refs/heads` directory; if so, this command should work from the repository's root:

```
del ".git\refs\heads\OneNote Table Of Contents.onetoc2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Git Extensions. Since spaces are not allowed in git, I bet those are other characters that you cannot type (it's strange how those sneaked in though). A decent GUI should be able to reproduce branch name for deletion purposes whatever it is.